# Transferring int variable between activities Android

Tags: android, variables, global

I am making a quiz game. However, I need to add a score variable that can be modified. The way the game works is it uses a few different activities. How can I transmit this score and modify it throughout the activities.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of passing an integer from one activity to another activity.

Start ActivityA and pass it the int like this:

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
theIntent.putExtra("somename", intVariable);  
startActivity(theIntent);
```

Get the integer from within ActivityA like this:

```
int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("somename");
```

Comment: What if Activity A was closed?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it was closed. As you modify the score just pass it along to the activities. Have each activity read the score in onCreate (or onResume) and initialize itself to the current score.

Answer (score 1):

trying this do not work in my activity onCreate-method. 
Method do need a default value as second parameter.

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(DetailClick.ID_NAME,-1);
```

Hope this helps!